# How to relax firewall for UDP connections/ports for a specific IP address?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables, redhat, udp

My server is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5`.

iptables version is **v1.3.5**.

I want to allow all UDP connections / port for the IP address `192.168.0.200`. This IP address is configured in my eth0.  So basically I want to set it up the same as my local  loopback (127.0.0.1) UDP traffic.

What is the `iptable` command to allow all UDP connections / ports for IP `192.168.0.200`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic command is:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp -d 192.168.0.200 -j ACCEPT
```

This will add the rule at the beginning of the `INPUT` chain. You may need to specify a different chain depending on what your current rules look like though. See the `iptables(8)` man page for more details.

Also, the rule is for all packets going *to* .200. If you meant packets coming *from* .200 then change the `-d` to `-s`.

Comment: @Ignacio In case, if I want to set it up either way.  Is it valid to execute both commands `iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp -d 192.168.0.200 -j ACCEPT` and `iptables -I INPUT 1 -p udp -s 192.168.0.200 -j ACCEPT`.  Or is there a single command to do this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do both. Since this is on the `INPUT` chain, only one of the endpoints can be .200. If it's the local machine then use `-d`, otherwise use `-s`.

Comment: What does `1` after `INPUT` mean?